# I have to add Operation Contract and implementation from different class library to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have class library in which Operation Contract and implementation are present, I want to add those contract run-time to WCF Service..

1) is it feasible ?

2) If 'Yes' then How to do that..

Comment: What have you tried? People on Stack Overflow will help you, but they won't do your work for you. You should read this and then edit your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/